# Why use do/else keywords to if in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Been working on learning Elixir, and I'm a little curious about the different ways of doing a single-line if/else.

I started with...

```
if left_side_wins?(p, c) do
  {"Humanity", p, c}
else
  {"The Machine", c, p}
end
|> print_winner
```

... which pipes the tuple properly for either winner. But *this* doesn't...

```
if left_side_wins?(p, c), do: {"Humanity", p, c}, else: {"The Machine", c, p}
|> print_winner
```

... and I *know* it's because the `|>` is considered part of the `else`, and I can fix it with parentheses...

```
if(left_side_wins?(p, c), do: {"Humanity", p, c}, else: {"The Machine", c, p})
|> print_winner
```

... and this now works. For either winner, the tuple is piped to `print_winner` properly.

But I could *also* use an inline do/else/end block and do...

```
if left_side_wins?(p, c) do {"Humanity", p, c} else {"The Machine", c, p} end
|> print_winner
```

... which works as well.

Every resource I've read describes using the `do:.., else:..` format, but the `do ... else ... end` seems both cleaner and less error-prone.

What are the major differences between them, beyond what I'm seeing?

The `do: ..., else: ...` seems to be preferred, but isn't it more sensitive to operator precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that `do: else:` is preferred. It is just there if you like it. They expand to the same thing, but as you discovered the operator precedence is different. `|>` is not greedy, so it tries to get minimal expression on its left:

```
if condition?, do: true_part, else: false_part |> print_winner
```

which is:

```
if condition?, do: true_part, else: (false_part |> print_winner)
```

which is:

```
if condition?, do: true_part, else: print_winner(false_part)
```

which in some cases may be what you actually want. The pipe operator becomes part of the else expression. In case of `if do end` syntax.

```
if condition? do true_part else false_part end |> print_winner
```

it is the same as:

```
print_winner(if condition? do true_part else false_part end)
```

The style guides advise to always start chain of pipes with "raw value", so linters would yell at you. The safest way would be to assign result of if expression which makes the pipeline useless:

```
winner = if left_side_wins?(p, c), do: {"Humanity", p, c}, else: {"The Machine", c, p}
print_winner(winner)
```

or to take the if expression into its own function:

```
def determine_winner({p, c}) do
  if left_side_wins?(p, c), do: {"Humanity", p, c}, else: {"The Machine", c, p}
end

{p, c}
|> determine_winner
|> print_winner
```

Comment: Great discussion, thank you! Are any of the choices more frowned upon than others, or are they generally all accepted as being "Elixirish" and used in different situations? Regardless, the  "... always start chain of pipes with raw value.." and "...take if expression into its own function" are **great** pieces of advice.

Comment: They are both Elixirish. I see people arguing that if there is only one expression in do and else than it should use `, do: else:` and to leave `do else end` for cases where there are multiple expressions. But personally even in case of single expressions I just check what looks nicer. If everything in a single line has less than 80 characters I use `, do: else:` otherwise `do else end`. Check out Credo linter https://github.com/rrrene/credo It checks your code for such things :) It is cool learning tool!

Answer (score 2):

Actually the syntax:

```
if condition do
# something
else 
# something else
end
```

is translated to form `if condition, do: , else:`

Using first option is more readable and it's more Ruby's syntax. Using second option can save you some unnecessary lines of code, but technically is purely the same. 
About the operator precedence- rules are the same. And about pipe operator - always use parentheses around expressions.

Comment: "... always use parentheses around expressions" I like that, good thought!